# Css style priorities with links

Tags: css

I have a `<div>` with a class that gives it the color blue, but the color blue does not appear. I do not understand why?

- Is this because a has priority over the class blue? I tried: a `.blue{}` as it is more specific it should win, is that wrong?
- If I delete "Some link" then it works. Why? I do not see the relation

Here is the example to check:

```css
a {
    outline:0;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:link, a:visited {
    color:black;
}
a:hover {
    color:black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.blue {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Some text, some text</p>
<p>
    <a href="http://apple.com"> Some link </a>
<p>
<a href="next.php">
    <div class="blue"> This text should be blue </div>
</a>
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6du7Lma5/)

Comment: try to fix the malformed markup: you didn't closed your second <p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to close your `<p>` tag:

```
<p><a href="http://apple.com"> Some link </a></p>
```

Comment: ups! stupid error. I have been so much time in fromt of this and I did not see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try the following :

```
a { outline:0; text-decoration:none ; }
a:link, 
a:visited { color:black; }
a:hover { color:black; text-decoration: none; }
```

.blue { color:blue; }

```
<p> Some text, some text </p>

<p><a href="http://apple.com"> Some link </a></p> 

<a href="next.php">
<span class="blue"> This text should be blue </span>
</a>
```

Chrome was correcting your code and placing the div with the blue class outside of the a tag as it is a block element and the a is not.

**Note: the malformed p tag solved it**